# LIKE but exclude one post by id?

Tags: mysql

can someone help me to make sql select

sample DB

```
ID | name | desc
23 | saya | ..
25 | saya-2 | ..
26 | saya-3 | ..
27 | wayan-wahyu | ..
```

i select db by

```
SELECT count(id) FROM data WHERE name like %:name%
```

but i want to exclude exclude id 23 from count will display total is 2

Comment: Are you having issues with the binding? Please add PHP, or remove PHP and show native SQL. This looks like a mash up of the two.

Comment: already answer by Rakesh Jakhar thanks for comment

Comment: On a sidenote: This should be `count(*)`, not `count(id)`, because you don't want to exclude null IDs from the count. The IDs are not null by definition, so it's rows you want to count rows. This won't make any difference in the result or the execution plan the DBMS uses to run your query. It's merely a matter of readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT count(id) FROM data WHERE ID != 23 AND name like %:name%
```